# When js files of draggable box include in php,It misses the draggable property

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

When I put draggable box js file under php code. It missed the property of draggable.

The code is like that:

```
    <?php
     Class Demo {
      Function test()
      {
        $response="";
        $abcContent=$this->getContent($x,$y,$z,$k)
        if($abcContent!="")
              {
               $response.="<div id=\"columns\"><table class=\"myTable\" >";
               $response.="<tr><td align=\"center\" width=\"30%\">";
               $response.="<ul id=\"column1\" class=\"column\"><li class=\"widget color-blue\"><div class=\"widget-head\"><h3>abc</h3></div><div class=\"widget-content\"><p>";
               $response.=$abcContent;
               $response.="</p></div></li></ul></td></tr></table></div>";
               }
             }
          }
        ?>
```

Note: I include js files and css files of draggable boxes in design page and content came from above class which is define in another .php page.

Comment: What draggable box do you mean? from jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't play any significant role here. PHP runs on the server, JS in the user's browser.
Everything depends on how your insert this piece of HTML code into the page and the code of the page generated with PHP should be shown instead of this one.

ps: if you insert this HTML code into the page with the help of AJAX or any other way after the main page with js files of draggable core is already loaded and initialized then, of course, you have run initialization of the draggable component again in order to take into account the updated DOM structure of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell jQuery where you want you dragable div. For example:

```
$( "#columns" ).draggable();
```

Have a look at the [manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Comment: <div id="columns">
        
        <ul id="column1" class="column">
            <li class="widget color-green" id="intro">
                <div class="widget-head">
                    <h3>Introduction</h3>
                </div>